# Accessing Federal Data via SOAP Webservice using SUDS in Python

Tags: python, xml, web-services, soap, suds

I am trying to access the Webservice of the Business Register of the Swiss Federal Government (https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/de/home/register/unternehmensregister/unternehmens-identifikationsnummer/uid-register/uid-schnittstellen.assetdetail.1760903.html)

However their documentation is so complex and weird that I have no clue on how to build the request that it works.

I am rather familiar with REST APIs but SOAP is new to me.

Using SoapUI I managed to build a working request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    xmlns:uid="http://www.uid.admin.ch/xmlns/uid-wse" xmlns:ns="http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0108-f/3" xmlns:ns1="http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0098-f/3" xmlns:ns2="http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0097-f/2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0046-f/3" xmlns:ns4="http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0044-f/4" xmlns:ns5="http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0010-f/6" xmlns:ns6="http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0007-f/6">
<soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <uid:Search>
      <uid:searchParameters>
        <ns:organisation>
          <ns1:organisationIdentification>
              <ns2:organisationName>Beekeeper</ns2:organisationName>
           </ns1:organisationIdentification>
        </ns:organisation>
     </uid:searchParameters>
  </uid:Search>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I am failing to implement this request in Python. Whatever tutorials I look up i find things such as

```
 request_data = client.factory.create('s1:CityWeatherRequest')
 request_data.City = "Stockholm"
```

What would the methods be to build the request as above?

How do I create nested requests to SOAP?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [pyxb](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/)

When you have built up Python bindings based on wsdl schema or xsd files, you can execute the code below to make the request. The [wsld](https://www.uid-wse-a.admin.ch/V3.0/PublicServices.svc?wsdl) shows what your actions will be.

```python
from pyxb.utils.six.moves.urllib import request as urllib_request
import pyxb.bundles.wssplat.soap11 as soapenv

# Create a SOAP envelope from XML
myenv = soapenv.Envelope(soapenv.Body(myxmlreq))

# Create URL, headers and body for the HTTP request
url="http://www.test.com"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
           'SOAPAction': "http://test.com/API/Action", # See documentation to learn about the actions
           'Connection':'close'} # set what your server accepts
body = myenv.toxml("utf-8")

# Create the request, send it and receive the response as XML
uri = urllib_request.Request(url,data=body,headers=headers)
rxml = urllib_request.urlopen(uri).read() # This is the response XML
```